# How to stop DraftJS cursor jumping to beginning of text?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

Code involved using DraftJS and Meteor Js application
Task - Make a live preview where text from DraftJS will get saved to DB and from DB it get displayed on another component.

But problem is once data comes from DB and I try to edit DraftJS cursor moved to the beginning.

Code is

```
import {Editor, EditorState, ContentState} from 'draft-js';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TestDB } from '../api/yaml-component.js';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class EditorComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        editorState : EditorState.createEmpty(),
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('Receiving Props');
    if (!nextProps) return;
    console.log(nextProps);
    let j = nextProps.testDB[0];
    let c = ContentState.createFromText(j.text);
    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(c),
    })
  }

  insertToDB(finalComponentStructure) {
    if (!finalComponentStructure) return;
    finalComponentStructure.author = 'Sandeep3005';
    Meteor.call('testDB.insert', finalComponentStructure);
  }


  _handleChange(editorState) {
    console.log('Inside handle change');
    let contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
    this.insertToDB({text: contentState.getPlainText()});
    this.setState({editorState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Editor
          placeholder="Insert YAML Here"
          editorState={this.state.editorState}
          onChange={this._handleChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


    EditorComponent.propTypes = {
     staff: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    };

    export default createContainer(() => {
      return {
        staff: Staff.find({}).fetch(),
      };
    }, EditorComponent);
```

Any helpful comment in right direction will be useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `EditorState.createWithContent(c)` Draft will return a new `EditorState` for you, but it has no idea about your current `SelectionState`. Instead, it will just create a new empty selection in the first block of your new `ContentState`.

To overcome this, you will have to set the `SelectionState` yourself,  using the `SelectionState` from your current state, e.g:

```
const stateWithContent = EditorState.createWithContent(c)
const currentSelection = this.state.editorState.getSelection()
const stateWithContentAndSelection = EditorState.forceSelection(stateWithContent, currentSelection)

this.setState({
  editorState: stateWithContentAndSelection
})
```

Comment: How do you keep the placeholder in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is a propery to move focus to end:

```
const newState = EditorState.createEmpty()
this.setState({
 editorState:
  EditorState.moveFocusToEnd(newState)
 })
```

This works for me.

Comment: This solution will cause the cursor to always have focus at the end. If the user changed the cursor to the middle it would still jump to the end.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to pass your given `EditorState` inside built in static `EditorState.moveSelectionToEnd()` method:

```
const editorState = EditorState.createEmpty();
const editorStateWithFocusOnTheEnd = EditorState.moveSelectionToEnd(editorState)
```